# Regex for nested balanced paren that starts from a word including certain words inside

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex that matches nested balanced paren that starts with certain word AND that includes different certain word somewhere inside the paren including child parens.

For example, I want to look for a parent paren that starts with `log` and that contains `email` somewhere in itself or it's child parens. Example lines looks like this:

```
Match
(log (some stuff) email)
(log (some stuff email))

Not Match
(log (some stuff))
((some stuff) email)
```

Since this is dealing with nested structure, I probably have to use recursion but how can I include the conditions inside recursion?

Comment: You can't actually use regex to handle recursion. Even something simple such as checking if the number of open parentheses equals the number of closed parentheses isn't possible. Link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2008/10/15/regular-expression-limitations/ (it's old but regex hasn't changed since 2008).

Comment: What language or tool are you using?

Comment: @AaronKlein Uh, your link says: "*As a side note, there are several regex engines out there that support the notion of recursion.*" So yes, you can (sometimes).

Comment: You could use a look ahead -- [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1MwGBr/1/) This is not detecting unbalanced parenthesis however. You would need recursive regex or a parser to do that.

Comment: @AaronKlein you can do recursion in regex. Please see https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html For example "\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)" will match all nested paren recursively. What I can't figure out is how I can specify the conditions into the regex expression.

Comment: It would be easiest to grab the `(log` ... `)`  substrings with a [`(?=\(log)(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))`](https://regex101.com/r/1WWdM1/1) regex and then just filter out the matches with the word `email` in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't write which flavour of regex you use, so I assumed
*PCRE* version.

You can use a 2-step approach.

The first regex is:

```
(?=\(log\b)(\((?:[^()]+|(?1))+\))
```

Description:

- `(?=\(log\b)` - Positive lookahead. Assert that the starting point
  is an opening parenthesis and then `log` and the word boundary.
- `(` - Start of the capturing group, needed for recursion.

  - `\(` - Opening parenthesis.

    - `(?:` - Start of the non-capturing group, needed due to repetition.
    - `[^()]+` - First alternative: A sequence of chars other than both
      parentheses.
    - `|` - Or.
    - `(?1)` - Second alternative: nested parentheses group (recursion).
    - `)+` - End of the non-capturing group, may occur multiple times.
  - `\)` - Closing parenthesis.
- `)` - End of the capturing group.

Due to the repetition of the non-capturing group, this regex matches
even cases like:

```
(log (aaa bbb ccc) xxx (ddd eee email) zzz)
```

where outer parentheses contain more than one inner parentheses group.

Then the match just found has to be tested whether is contains `email`,
anywhere, but as a single word (not concatenated with something else like
`xxemail`).
The second regex is just `\bemail\b`, but remember that it has to be applied
to just the first match and **nothing more**.

Otherwise there could be a *false positive* case, if `email` was
located somewhere further in the original text (behind the match just found).

Caution: If you use e.g. Javascript regex, then you are in trouble, as
Javascript regex (and some other too) does not suport recursion.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add a flavor. I was using grep with -P, so I assume it's PCRE. I was trying to do this in one regex but looks I was fighting a battle to lose. You solution indeed works for my problem.

Comment: Just for curiosity, could you give me a logical explanation why this is impossible with one regex?

Comment: I tried to add a dedicated capturing group for "email". Unfortunately, this group captures such word only on the "main level", but not within recursive calls. It turns out that recursion in regex has some limitations, not so obvious at the first glance.